# java repaint blocks out jbutton

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jbutton, jcomponent

Inside my paintComponent() method, I have a drawRect() that paints the background of a jpanel. But because the jbutton is drawn on the screen before the paintComponent() method gets called, the jbutton is blocked out by the drawRect. Does anyone know how to fix this? My guess is to add the jbutton before repaint gets called, but I don't know how to do that?

Some code:

```
public Frame(){
  add(new JButton());
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
  super.paintComponent(g);
  g.drawRect(0,0,screenwidth,screenheight); //paints the background with a color 
                                            //but blocks out the jbutton.
}
```

Comment: Does `Frame` extend `JFrame`?

Comment: This is strange code indeed since I agree with Jeffrey that you appear to be trying to override a `paintComponent(...)` method for a JFrame class which shouldn't happen. Please put an `@Override` before your `paintComponent(...)` method. Make sure that you're overriding `paintComponent(...)` and **not** `paintComponents(...)` because there's a **big** difference. It would be nice if you could post an [sscce](http://sscce.org) that let us see and experience your problem first hand.

Comment: Ok i edited the post, this is just an example code that i quickly typed not my actual project

Comment: What were you doing wrong? How did you fix it? Note that it's almost always better to post actual code rather than unrelated code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels As a matter of fact, it can't happen. `JFrame` does not have a `paintComponent` method.

Comment: You understand what i mean by the question so just ignore the errors.

Comment: @Jeffrey: exactly. Of course a class that extends JFrame can have a `paintComponent` method, but it's not a true override which is why the `@Override` annotation can help. Of course the super method call would have thrown a compiler error in that situation I see.

Comment: Ewen: that's the problem. When we don't know yet what's causing your main problem, we can't ignore any errors. That's why it's almost always best to post real code.

Comment: Ok i get the paintComponent thing but thats not the point.

Comment: The problem is the rectangle covers the jbutton because its on a higher layer

Comment: The point Ewen is that based on the information you've so far presented, it's impossible to answer your question. You have two choices: present more information, best one that includes an [sscce](http://sscce.org) or close this question.

Comment: I'll add more info in a few minutes because im on kindle fire and its hard to type.

Comment: Complex questions should be asked from a computer that has a Java compiler and has the code that you're asking about. Otherwise you're setting yourself and us up for a bit of frustration.

Comment: OK, you've marked a "correct" answer but still haven't told us what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Now, firstly, I will tell you what you're doing wrong here -- `JFrame` is not a `JComponent`, and has no `paintComponent` for you to override. Your code will probably never be called. Aside from that, `drawRect` merely draws a rectangle -- it does *not* fill one.

---

However, I believe there is a proper way to do this.

Since you're using a `JFrame`, you should take advantage of the container's *layered pane* via [`JFrame.getLayeredPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#getLayeredPane()).

> A layered pane is a container with depth such that overlapping components can appear one on top of the other. General information about layered panes is in [How to Use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html). This section discusses the particulars of how root panes use layered panes.

[image]

*Root panes* are covered in [How to Use Root Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html), a part of the Java Tutorials. A layered pane is a child of the root pane, and a `JFrame`, as a top-level container, utilizes an underlying `JRootPane`.

Anyways, since you're interested in creating a background, see the following diagram for how a layered pane generally looks inside a top-level container:

[image]

> The table below describes the intended use for each layer and lists the JLayeredPane constant that corresponds to each layer:
>
> **Layer Name** - **Value** - **Description**
>
> `FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER`  - `new Integer(-30000)` - The root pane adds the menu bar and content pane to its layered pane at this depth.

Since we want to specify our background is behind the content, we first add it to the same layer ([`JLayeredPane.FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html#FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER)), as follows:

```
final JComponent background = new JComponent() {

  private final Dimension size = new Dimension(screenwidth, screenheight);

  private Dimension determineSize() {
    Insets insets = super.getInsets();
    return size = new Dimension(screenwidth + insets.left + insets.right,
        screenheight + insets.bottom + insets.top);
  }

  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return size == null ? determineSize() : size;
  }

  public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
    return size == null ? determineSize() : size;
  }

  protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, screenwidth, screenheight);
  }
};
final JLayeredPane layeredPane = frame.getLayeredPane();
layeredPane.add(background, JLayeredPane.FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER);
```

Now, to make sure we draw our background before the content, we use [`JLayeredPane.moveToBack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html#moveToBack(java.awt.Component)):

```
layeredPane.moveToBack(background);
```

Comment: The pictures come from the Oracle Java tutorials

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels indeed, which can easily be seen after clicking the links to the tutorials.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - Yeah I'm aware of that (I did actually read the tutorials ;)) - but you gotta love pretty pictures ;)

Comment: What if i'm drawing directly onto a jframe without a jpanel?

Comment: @veer What if i'm drawing directly onto a jframe without a jpanel?

Comment: @Yayatcm you can't :-) `JFrame` use a `JRootPane`, which uses a layered pane, which contains the content pane as well as menu bars, pop-ups, etc. and then a glass pane overlay. `JFrame.add` internally delegates to the content pane. Adding directly to the layered pane defaults to `0`, though you can specify (as we did) a Z-order from `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 5):

I did this really quick test.  As HovercraftFullOfEels has pointed out.  JFrame does not have a `paintComponent`, so I used a `JPanel` instead.

[image: Can you see me]

Which was produced by this code

```
public class PanelTest extends JPanel {

    private JButton button;

    public PanelTest() {

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        button = new JButton("Can you see me ?");
        add(button);

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        Rectangle bounds = button.getBounds();
        bounds.x -= 10;
        bounds.y -= 10;
        bounds.width += 20;
        bounds.height += 20;

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        ((Graphics2D)g).fill(bounds);

    }

}
```

I've I try and replicate the issue by using `paintComponents` on the `JFrame`, I don't see the rectangle.  Even if I overwrite `paint` on the `JFrame`, the rectangle is still painted under the button (Not that I would ever recommend doing either).

The problem is, you haven't given us enough code to know what's going wrong

ps - `drawRect` won't "fill" anything

Comment: I'm guessing that there's some bad smelling code going on, perhaps he's trying to add components from within paintComponent -- hard to guess.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels it could be a heavy/light weight issue, I'm just making wild assumptions, which is never a clever idea :P

Comment: is the gridbaglayout required?

Comment: @Ewen No, I just want to place the button on the pane in way that it wouldn't try and fill the available area. It's an example nothing more

Comment: ok, also, can you do add(new JButton()); inside the paintComponent()?

Comment: I did t add it inside paintcomponent, i just thought of it.

Comment: I added bounds to not fill with color so that jbutton wont get covered

Comment: @Ewen: that doesn't answer my question. You don't need to use kludges to prevent components from being drawn over which suggests that something is still very wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this before, although not jframe specifically and not the kind of the scenario that you have. Try this code,

```
    this.getContentPane.repaint();
```

on your jframe. Im not sure about this, but give it a try.

Comment: And what does this do? Can you explain more?

Comment: Its been a while since I've done java GUI, but it simply reloads or cleans every component in a frame. Cleans means not removing your drawing, but polishes the design declaration on your component. Im not sure how java docs explain it, that is only based on my own understanding. I used this code whenever I have to load a picture inside a jDesktopPane.

Comment: I think that code snippet will work if you properly declared it somewhere in your code (ie. after you have drawn your rectangle). Good Luck!